# How correct create dynamiclly select with horizontal orientation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want danamically create `select` element in horizontal block. And have funny result. What is the correct way?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgulaev/VMj4U/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define where you want to append the new elements. For this, use `.after()`. And then you need to apply styles on the generated/modified controlgroup.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/rKGtQ/

Code:

```
// append select menu after Button div
$("#Button_show_filters").after('<select id="sm"><option>Opt 1</option><option>Opt 2</option></select>');

// apply styles on select menu
$("#sm").selectmenu();

// add options to controlgroup 
$( "#test" ).controlgroup( "option", "corners", true );

// create controlgroup
$( "#test" ).controlgroup().trigger('create');
```

*controlgroup div ID is `#test`.*

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that every time the "Push me!!" button is pressed, you are appending a select element with an `id` attribute of `sm`. Having multiple elements with the same id is invalid HTML and can cause problems with Javascript. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute).

Namely, the `$("#sm")` line doesn't know which select you are trying to target.

Maybe you should try something like this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("#div_for_harakteristikinomenklatury_list").append('<select><option>Opt 1</option><option>Opt 2</option></select>');
    $("#div_for_harakteristikinomenklatury_list select:last").selectmenu();
});
```

Also, you should get rid of the `onclick` attribute for the button. You don't need it. Passing the click handler to the `click` function should make the function run when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using id you should use class and apply selctmenu only on last appended select element. Check this fiddle

```
$("button").click(function show_filters() {
//alert("Hello");
    $("#div_for_harakteristikinomenklatury_list").append('<select class="sm"><option>Opt 1</option><option>Opt 2</option></select>');
    $(".sm:last").selectmenu();
})
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VMj4U/4/)

Comment: But we have the same. New select element at the Rigth, but it will be on the Left side

Answer (score 0):

change the `$("#sm").selectmenu();` to `$("select").selectmenu();`

With above mentioned method no matter what is the id or class of the element you newly pushed, it'll get the styles applied.

Check the live fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/VMj4U/6/