# JS always selected 1 of 2 checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes in my page. First id is "status_1", second id is "status_2"

I want to make that both of them must be selected on page load and always keep one selected, when trying to deselect both.

So for example if "status_1" is selected, "status_2" is not selected and user is trying do deselect "status_1" too, "status_2" select automatically.

Comment: nice idea, please add your code as well.

Comment: so add onchange event, if current is unchecked, check the other..... seems like a simple thing  to do.

Comment: Typically the control you would use for "must select one or the other" is either a single on/off style checkbox or a two-state radio button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check checkbox if another checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372829/check-checkbox-if-another-checkbox-is-checked) - but then the opposite :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice welcome gift for a new user on this website :-)
Normally we'd like to see what you have tried yourself, so we have some proof of effort since StackOverflow isn't a free programming service.

This code subscribes to the `onchange` event of the two checkboxes and checks the other one if both are unchecked. Since the actual logic is the same for each case I have moved it to a function to avoid repeating code.

```js
function checkOther(a, b)
{
  if (!a.checked && !b.checked)
    b.checked = true;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var s1 = document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox'][name='status_1']");
  var s2 = document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox'][name='status_2']");
  s1.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    checkOther(e.target, s2);
  });
  s2.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    checkOther(e.target, s1);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="status_1" checked="checked" /> 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="status_2" checked="checked" /> 2
```

Comment: If this code is used, use the newer `addEventListener` instead of the legacy `onchange` property.

Comment: Wow, that is just what I wanted!
Next time I will give my code:)
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!$("#checkbox1").is(":checked") && !$("#checkbox2").is(":checked")) {
    // both of them are unchecked u can eather check one or drop error
}
```

you can initiate it on change of element so.

```
$("#checkbox1").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

so in theory, you could create a function that checks if both unchecked and complete it with callback.

Comment: jQuery isn’t mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: So him having an option for it (Maybe he doesn't know about it, since hes missing one tag) is wrong? That's why its a minus right. Hens my nickname.. If there is a better answer (which there is) it will for sure have more up votes then this. But you sir are a definition of a grumpy cat. :> Have a lovely day :)

Comment: Neither the OP nor you mentioned jQuery anywhere. It’s not appropriate to answer with jQuery, when the OP didn’t explicitly ask for jQuery.

Comment: @Xufox Well if he doesn't know about it, how would he know, if you go to a coffee shop, you decide ether you want black or light in there, eather you feel like eating desert or some lunch, don't you. However you did explain how should I improve my answer now (which how it's supposed to be), so it makes sense and adds up now.