# Prepend some object to parent, which is one of the DIVs with similar ID

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like my code to work like this: There are few DIVs with similar ID and similar content. When I click on CLICK button i need already existing DIV id="object" to prepend to parent div of the click button. My code works just for the first of DIVs.

HTML

```
<div id="article">
<p>...CONTENT</p>
<div class="click">CLICK</div>
</div>

<div id="article">
<p>...CONTENT</p>
<div class="click">CLICK</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#article{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: gray;
    color: white;
}

.click{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
}

#object{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(".click").click(function(){
    $('#object').prependTo("#article");
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teLgd00j/1/)

Comment: _There are few DIVs with **similar** ID_ is not correct. ID must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first, having the same ID for multiple elements is bad, bad, bad.
See [Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute). You can use classes instead

```
<div class="article">
<p>...CONTENT</p>
<div class="click">CLICK</div>
</div>

<div class="article">
<p>...CONTENT</p>
<div class="click">CLICK</div>
</div>
```

To prepend to the closest div in question, you can use jQuery `closest()` with `$(this)` which will be the 'clicked' div when it enters the handler

```
$(this).closest('.article').prepend($('#object'));
```

See it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/teLgd00j/2/)