# Dynamically appending value to a link produces wrong results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple table containing user details (user id in the provided example). There's a link available for each record. This link (in real) is dynamically generated based on no.of records. each record will have a link. And upon clicking this link, that corresponding user's id has to be passed (appended) to another link (which I refer as user link in the example).

**My HTML Code:**

```
<a id="abc" href="aa/">User Link</a>
<hr>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td><a id="xyz" data-userid="100" href="#">first user</a></td>
    <td>100</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><a id="xyz" data-userid="200" href="#">second user</a></td>
    <td>200</td>
</tr> 

<tr>
    <td><a id="xyz" data-userid="300" href="#">third user</a></td>
    <td>300</td>
</tr>     
</table>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).on('click','#xyz',function(e){
     var uid = $(this).attr('data-userid');
     $('#abc').attr('href',$('#abc').attr('href')+uid);
});
```

I am appending the user id to the User Link based on the above jQuery code.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

`<a id="abc" href="aa/100">User Link</a>` for first user

`<a id="abc" href="aa/200">User Link</a>` for second user

`<a id="abc" href="aa/300">User Link</a>` for third user

which I get partially.

**Issue**:

When I click a second link after clicking a previous one, both the values are appending to the end of User Link.

For example, If I click first user initially, User Link becomes

```
<a id="abc" href="aa/100">User Link</a>
```

and then if I click second user, User Link becomes

```
<a id="abc" href="aa/100200">User Link</a>
```

and so on...which is not what I am trying to get.
Where did I make mistake???

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/5uhdjd1c/2/).

**P.S**: use Inspect Element from browser to see this mess in live action.

Comment: `id="xyz"`. Two or more elements cannot have same ID : Invalid HTML

Comment: Actually this User Link is in a popup modal which is used for all records. @Tushar

Comment: Ok forget id. what if it was a class?? @Shaunak D

Comment: U cant say Forget ID.. Modify the question and are you expecting the result to be href="aa/100/200"..?

Comment: What is the point of making users click 2 times ? Why don't you generate the user links with the corresponding url ?

Comment: Actually this is not how it originally looks. On clicking the link from table, a modal pop-up will show & some operations there & inside that modal pop-up, there's a link to which I have to append the value. For simplicity, I made it look like this. @w35l3y

Comment: No I am not expecting that. I have included the sample result in the question itself. @Riddler

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, do not have multiple elements with the same id. See

[Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute)

Second, store the initial href in a var like

```
var initialHref = $('#abc').attr('href');
```

and change

```
$('#abc').attr('href',$('#abc').attr('href')+uid);
```

to

```
$('#abc').attr('href',initialHref+uid);
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5uhdjd1c/6/)

Comment: This doesn't work if link is something link gotohere.com/abc/ggg/another/ @AmmarCSE

Answer (score 0):

Few issues:

- Change IDs to classes in your markup `class="xyz"` and in the `click` handler `.xyz`
- Store the initial `href` value to access it on subsequent clicks.

---

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uhdjd1c/5/)**

```
var initHref = $('#abc').attr('href')
$(document).on('click','.xyz',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();                      // Prevent default action of `<a>`
     var uid = $(this).attr('data-userid');   //or $(this).data('userid');
     $('#abc').attr('href',initHref+uid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to store the href of the user link and use it later to append the new value, like below.

P.S. please change **ID `xyz` to class**

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3z3vz53/)

```
$(function() {
    var userLink = $('#abc')[0];
    var linkHref = userLink.href;

    $(document).on('click','.xyz',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Cancels the default behaviour
        var uid = $(this).attr('data-userid');
        userLink.href = linkHref + uid;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you used `data-userid`, you may use `data-href` in the first link to store your initial and unmodified url.

And then use something similar to:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".xyz", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var userLink = $("#abc");
        userLink.attr("href", userLink.attr("data-href") + $(this).attr("data-userid"));
    });
});
```