# How do I get the name of a Div that has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the following html

```
<div id="chatid" name="1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50/55C1E7/fff" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" /> John
</div>
<div id="chatid" name="2">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50/55C1E7/fff" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" /> James
</div>
```

I am using the following jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chatid").click(function() {
    thread = $(this).attr('name');
    $("#chatmessages").load('fetchmessages.php?id=' + thread);
    //alert($(this).attr('name'));
    return false;
  });
});
```

This only gives the name when clicking on the first "chatid" Div, is there a way for me to return the name of any "chatid" Div?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it's just for the sake of example but it's a bad idea to have multiple `id` attributes with the same name.

Comment: You've got invalid HTML, please validate your HTML with this validator: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input HINT: You use 2 times the same ID, this causes to 'crash' your CSS & JS

Comment: `id` is Unique don't use repeatedly. Replace id as a class and  `thread` declare it `var thread`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is unique don't use repeatedly

```
<div class="chatid" name="1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50/55C1E7/fff" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" /> John
</div>
<div class="chatid" name="2">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50/55C1E7/fff" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" /> James
</div>
```

JavaScript is

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chatid").click(function() {
    var thread = $(this).attr('name');
    //$("#chatmessages").load('fetchmessages.php?id=' + thread);
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
    return false;
  });
});
```

Working example is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/k0ej7ckx/)

Answer (score 8):

```
$('div').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Additionally, do not use the same ID for multiple elements as this is bad practice. Use classes instead.

See [Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute)

Answer (score 3):

You have invalid html. There can be only one element with given id.

Use class instead:

`<div class="chatid" name="1">`

then your selector will be:

```
$(".chatid").click( //do something );
```