# Adding multiple GET Parameters to URL using window.location.assign from checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, window.location

I'm trying to use JavaScript to add parameters to the current URL in order to filter WordPress posts. Example: `http://domain.com/houses/?rooms=1,2&bath=1&yard=yes`

I have successfully done this with one of the parameters, but I'm failing in understanding how to add on multiple parameters. What is the proper way of getting this one?

Also, is using `window.location.assign()`, the proper way for adding the parameters to the URL? Is using AJAX better/safer?

Below is my code

**HTML**

```
<div id="filter-rooms">
       <ul>
           <li>
               <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rooms" />1 Room</li>
           <li>
               <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="rooms" />2 Rooms</li>
           <li>
               <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="rooms" />3 Rooms</li>
           <li>
               <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="rooms" />4 Rooms</li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div id="filter-bath">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="bath" />1 Bathrooms</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="bath" />2 Bathrooms</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="bath" />3 Bathrooms</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="filter-yard">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="yard" value="yes" id="yard" />Yes</li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="yard" value="no" id="yard" />No</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#filter-rooms').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {

    var $ul = $(this).closest('ul'),
        vals = [];

    $ul.find('input:checked').each(function () {

        vals.push($(this).val());

    });

    vals = vals.join(",");

    window.location.assign('?rooms=' + vals);

});
```

Now, in the JavaScript displayed above, I managed to get the rooms parameter successfully working, but when I duplicate this for the other parameters, it replaces the URL with the rooms parameter instead of adding it on to the end of the URL like so - `&bath=1&yard=yes`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9Laforb/1/
*(Note: window.location.assign() is missing because jsFiddle doesn't allow it.)*

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, do not use the same `id` on multiple elements.
See [Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute)

Your problem is with this line

```
 window.location.assign('?rooms=' + vals);
```

You need to dynamically update the query string.

Using this method

```
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}
```

from [add or update query string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter)

and custom attributes like

```
<ul data-type="rooms">
```

you can do

```
window.location.href = updateQueryStringParameter(window.location.href, $ul.attr('data-type'), vals);
```

instead of

```
window.location.assign('?rooms=' + vals);
```

Comment: AmmarCSE, thanks for the advice. I actually didn't realize I was using the same ID on multiple elements.  As far as the JavaScript, I'm a little confused as how this works. I tried implementing this and the the URL did not update at all. Should the first parameter inside the updateQueryStringParameter method be window.location or window.location.assign?

Comment: @iammikerodriguez, sorry, my mistake. Use window.location.href

Comment: AmmarCSE, Unfortunately, it's still not adding the parameters to the URL.

Comment: @iammikerodriguez, try window.location.href = updateQueryStringParameter(..... instead of updateQueryStringParameter(.... by itself

Comment: AmmarCSE, that worked in getting the page to reload, but instead I'm getting this when the URL changes: /rooms?1=undefined instead of /?rooms=1

Comment: @iammikerodriguez, this is because the `vals` you are passing in is undefined

Comment: AmmarCSE, When I console.log the `vals`, I'm successfully getting the defined values. The format of the added parameters is wrong. I'm should be getting `domain.com/houses/?rooms=1` but instead I'm getting `domain.com/houses/rooms?1=`

Comment: @iammikerodriguez, can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: AmmarCSE, jsFiddle filters out the window.location line, but here is a fiddle of the rest of the code http://jsfiddle.net/p73zvnaL/2/ CodePen, doesn't filter it out, however. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waoLyz

Comment: @AmmarCSE - console.log is correctly spitting out the values. Here is the updated jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/p73zvnaL/3/

Comment: @iammikerodriguez, no I mean, see the console.log(test) at the end of http://jsfiddle.net/p73zvnaL/2/ it is correctly changing the url

Comment: @AmmarCSE Sorry, there isn't any console.log statement at the end of http://jsfiddle.net/p73zvnaL/2/ I think jsFiddle is removing it

Comment: @iammikerodriguez, wow your right! sorry. Ok, put this at the end:  var test = window.location.href = updateQueryStringParameter(window.location.href, $ul.attr('data-type'), vals);
    console.log(test);

Comment: Thanks for that. It's showing the URL now. Just have to work out some bugs on it.

Comment: @iammikerodriguez, ok, let me know if you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

Try this : define variables to store rooms, bath and yard selected values and create url accordingly in each change handler of inputs.

```
roomVal = '';
bathVal = '';
yardVal = '';

$('#filter-rooms').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
     roomVal = $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(i,v){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    window.location.assign('?rooms=' + roomVal + '&bath='+bathVal+"&yard="+yardVal);
});

$('#filter-bath').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
     bathVal = $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(i,v){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    window.location.assign('?rooms=' + roomVal + '&bath='+bathVal+"&yard="+yardVal);
});

$('#filter-yard').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function () {
     yardVal = $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="radio"]:checked').map(function(i,v){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    window.location.assign('?rooms=' + roomVal + '&bath='+bathVal+"&yard="+yardVal);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9Laforb/6/)**

Comment: This method works, but it keeps replacing the clearing the URL parameters every time new parameter is added on.

Comment: To avoid this, you can just assign values to `roomsVal`, `bathVal` and `yardVal` in each change handler and when you do ajax call that time create your `window.location.assign` using these variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with `window.location.href`
If you have any value stored in a `variable`, you can use the `+` symbol to concatenate the value.

```
var somedata = somedata;

window.location.href = "http://www.yourwebsite.com?data1=somedata&data2="+somedata;
```