# How do I get the id of a list item?

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have a checkboxlist where each item has an id. When the text of an item is clicked the id("cssId") should be printed out in console.log.

Checkboxlist:

```
<div id="cssListBox" class="list-group">
            <ul id="listItemCss">
                @foreach (var item in Model.CssTemplates)
                {
                    <li id="itemInList">
                        @Html.CheckBox("ChoiceBox", item.IsConnected)
                        @Html.Hidden("cssId", item.Id, new { @class = "cssId" })
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#listItemCss>li').click(function() {
        var cid = (this).val();

        console.log('cid');
    });
```

Please tell me if I can make the question more clear in some way, I am a bit slow so have patience.

Comment: could you post the html that get's outputted rather than the text for the cshtml file please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#listItemCss>li').click(function() {
    var cid = $(this).find('.cssId').val();
    console.log(cid);
});
```

Also, don't use the same `id` for multiple `li` elements

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/q4w44s5e/)

See [Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute)

Comment: I get "undefined" in log when trying this.

Comment: @FadiY, like this it will not ....  foreach (var item in Model.CssTemplates)
                {
                    <li id="itemInList">

Comment: @FadiY, no it has nothing to do with it. Perhaps I misunderstood what you want. Do you want the value of cssId?

Comment: Yes I want value of cssId.

Comment: Now log says "false". I know I get Id because I can see generated items in browser.

Comment: @FadiY, can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry I cant do that since <li> are database objects.

Comment: @FadiY, just take the static html produced by the razor and put it in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#listItemCss>li').click(function() {
        var cid = (this).attr('id');

        console.log('cid');
    });
```

Comment: Providing an explanation to why your solution works will help your readers learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#listItemCss>li').click(function() {
        var cid = $(this).attr('id');

        console.log('cid');
    });
```