# Enable text area on change of Select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of **select box** and array of **text area** with same **id** and **class**.

```
  <div class="reasons">
       <select id="reason" class="reason_select" name="reason[]">
           <option>Please Select</option>
           <option value="misc">Misc</option>
        </select>
        <textarea id="reason_comment" name="reason_comment[]" disabled="disabled/>

        <select id="reason" class="reason_select" name="reason[]">
           <option>Please Select</option>
           <option value="misc">Misc</option>
        </select>
        <textarea id="reason_comment" name="reason_comment[]" disabled="disabled/>

        <select id="reason" class="reason_select" name="reason[]">
           <option>Please Select</option>
           <option value="misc">Misc</option>
        </select>
        <textarea id="reason_comment" name="reason_comment[]" disabled="disabled/>
  </div>
```

In these three pairs, on change of any of the select box I need to enable there corresponding textarea.

```
$(document).on("change", ".reason_select", function(){
    //not getting where to start and how to identify corresponding textarea.
});
```

Comment: I see multiple `id="reason_comment"` (like reason). It's not correct, an *id* is unique !

Comment: @Aure77 is right. this is the starting point of the way to go. most of the answers so far below do a next, this is bad as it ties the UI to a specific order. do selections either on id, class, or data attribute. IMHO any sequential selector should be avoided unless necessary or obvious like li in ul / options within a select, definitely not good in this case.

Comment: Totally agree multiple elements with same id is damm bad idea..will try to assign unique id to all elements

Comment: Thanks all of you for valuable answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Identifiers in HTML must be unique* A good read  [Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute)

You can use [`$.fn.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to traverse to immediate sibling.

*Use*

```
$(document).on("change", ".reason_select", function(){
    $(this).next('textarea').prop('disabled', false)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(document).on("change", ".reason_select", function(){
    $(this).next().prop("disabled",false)
});
```

Comment: Thanks..all of the answers above are same and working..I am confused..which answer i should mark right..

Comment: @PardeepDhingra That is your wish :)

Comment: upvote them all and give the accepted to the earliest correct

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Good... and Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

> not getting where to start and how to identify corresponding textarea.

The first place to start would be to not use the same id for multiple elements. See [Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute)

You can use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) instead

```
$(document).on("change", ".reason_select", function(){
    $(this).next('textarea').prop('disabled',false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **unique** IDs. Instead make it a class in your textboxes:

```
class="reason_comment"
^^^^^
```

And in jQuery:

```
 $(document).on("change", ".reason_select", function(){
  $(this).next('.reason_comment').prop('disabled',false);
 });
```