# Find the First child of all containers

Tags: jquery, html, ccss

I have a bunch of containers in a html page for example

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="details">
        <span id="Title">My Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <span id="Title">My Title</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="details">
        <span id="Title">My Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <span id="Title">My Title</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to target the first details class in each container and add a class to the Title Class with jQuery.

The JQuery Code I have, works perfectly, but only does this for the first container, and not the second or the third container class.

```
$('.container').closest('.Details:first').find('#Title').addClass('header');
```

So my ideal result should be :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="details">
        <span id="Title" class="header">My Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <span id="Title">My Title</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="details">
        <span id="Title" class="header">My Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <span id="Title">My Title</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Note that you have repeated the `#Title` `id` throughout your HTML which is incorrect. The `id` attribute of any element must be unique within a page. You need to change this before proceeding.

Comment: I don't see how the code you posted could work correctly for any elements. `.closest()` searches the ancestors, not the descendants. And there's no `class="Details"` in your HTML -- class names are case-sensitive.

Comment: See my answer below and let me know if this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `closest()` either use a **space** or `find()` to indicate descendants.
2. Use `:first-child` instead of `:first`
3. Do not use the same id for multiple elements. See [Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute)

```js
$('.container .details:first-child').find('.Title').addClass('header');
```

```css
.header{
  background:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="details">
    <span class="Title">My Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <span class="Title">My Title</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="details">

    <span class="Title">My Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <span class="Title">My Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps add some CSS for `.header` so we can see the result when running the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

As @Rory McCrossan stated attribute "id" must be unique.

See it this works:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Slico/3rpLwtvn/1/)

```
$(".container .details").children().addClass("header");
```

Comment: You don't need to use `.each` -- `.addClass` will automatically loop over all the elements.