# get the submit from a form espcific in same page with same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i trying get the submit from a form specific with jquery and alert the value of a field type hiden that contains the a value id;
i tried this.
but he is getting ever same id value.
here are the code jquery

```
var form = $(".form");

form.submit(function() {
    alert(form.find('#id').val());
    return false;
});
```

and here code html

```
<div>
    <form  action="" method="post" class="form">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="1" />
        <button class="submit"  type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>
<div/>
<div>
    <form  action="" method="post" class="form">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="2" />
        <button class="submit"  type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>
<div/>
<div>
    <form  action="" method="post" class="form">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="3" />
        <button class="submit"  type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>
<div/>
```

which my wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. But you need to use `$(this)` instead of `form`

The reason it was alerting the first value before is because when you do `$('.form').val()` it will get the first value by default, even if there are multiple elements. But, when you use `$(this)`, it will get the specific `.form` that was submitted.

Finally, avoid using the same id for multiple elements. You can use an alternative such as classes. See [Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute)

```js
var form = $(".form");

form.submit(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('.my-class').val());
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <form  action="" method="post" class="form">
        <input type="hidden" class="my-class" name="id" value="1" />
        <button class="submit"  type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>
<div/>
<div>
    <form  action="" method="post" class="form">
        <input type="hidden" class="my-class" name="id" value="2" />
        <button class="submit"  type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>
<div/>
<div>
    <form  action="" method="post" class="form">
        <input type="hidden" class="my-class" name="id" value="3" />
        <button class="submit"  type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>
<div/>
```

Comment: here now work, nice bro, and about cannot have id replay i remove ids and change for a class

Comment: @Ricardopatrickmarinhodesou, I updated the code snippet in my answer to use classes instead. Let me know if you still have questions

Comment: for now is just this :p ty bro

Comment: @Ricardopatrickmarinhodesou, hope it helped :). Like I said, let me know if you have further questions

Answer (score 2):

change

`form.find('#id').val()`

to 
`$(this).find('input').val()` or `$(this).find('#id').val()`

And of course, use unique IDs for each elements

Answer (score 1):

```
id="id"
```

Id is supposed to be unique no matter where it's located. Try changing it to `id="id1"` and `id="id2"` for example.

Answer (score 1):

First thing - don't create multiple DOM elements with the same ID value. ID value must be unique.