# jQuery: How to add the attribute in $(this)?

Tags: jquery

Example I have 10 textbox and each has the same attribute with different value, say for example they have an attribute `data-same` with different value and I have something like this in my code 
`$('#test').each(function(){
     $(this).val();
});`
and I want to filter the result using the attribute of each textbox. How would I do it? I was thinking on doing something like this
`$('#test').each(function(){
     $('[data-same="val1"]',this).val();
});`
but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do..... else your code seems to be fine...

Comment: so you mean i can use an attribute as a selector?

Comment: Yes, you can use. You should have tried that.

Comment: oh! thank you, I never thought that it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#test').each(function(){
     var attributeValue = $(this).attr('data-same');
     //do whatever you want with the value
});
```

Also, your code indicates you have the same ID for multiple elements. Avoid that and use classes or attributes instead.

```
$('[data-same]').each(function(){
         var attributeValue = $(this).attr('data-same');
         //do whatever you want with the value
    });
```

See [Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test').each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).attr("data-same") );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok If my assumption is correct you want to get all the `textbox` with same attribute then below code will work and I would suggest keep an unique `id`:
to each elements and you can try with `classname` instead say `class="test"`:

```
var sameTextBox=[];
$('.test').each(function(){ //change this selector to class
     if($(this).attr('data-same')=="somevalue") //otherwise you can try 
     //if($(this).data('same')=="somevalue")
     {
          sameTextBox.push($(this));
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `map` method to get all the textbox values.

```
$(function(){
   var textBoxValues = $('input[data-same]').map(function(){
   return this.value
   }).get()
})
```

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

you can use  jQuery filter method.

```
$(".test").filter(function(){ 
  if(parseInt($(this).attr('data-same')) == "somevalue")
   return $(this);
});
```

Note: Use class name for group of elements, and id for a single element.