# jQuery click event two elements with same id

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery click event like so:

`$('#header #navigation a').on('click', function() {`

I have two elements with the id navigation:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default communities-nav" id="navigation">`

and

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navigation" style="position: fixed; top: 0px;">`

I only want this onclick event to apply the element without the class `communities-nav` so I want to apply this onclick event to this element:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navigation" style="position: fixed; top: 0px;">`

Comment: Id's are supposed to be unique. Using the same id twice is only going to lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Like m69 mentioned, ids should be unique. If you would like to apply an action or styles to multiple units consider creating a class. If you would not like to use a class perhaps a child selection is the method for you.

Comment: Since ids are supposed to be **unique** you would not need a selector like this: `'#header #navigation a'` ..... **`'#navigation a'` would be sufficient.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not use the same id for multiple elements. See [Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute)
2. Use classes instead

---

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default communities-nav navigation">

and

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navigation" style="position: fixed; top: 0px;">
```

3. You can use [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

---

```
$('#header .navigation:not(.communities-nav) a').on('click', function() {
```