# How to take the inner text of id and assign it to a specific variable only for a specific inner text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have **different pages** which populate a div tag with a specific id based on the id inner text:
here are some different example of pages with this div:

```
<div id="id_name">text page1</div>
<div id="id_name">text page2</div>
<div id="id_name">text page3</div>
```

I want to take only the inner text of second and fill a variable.

I try to use something like this:

```
if($("#id_name").length > 0 && $("#id_name").text() === "text page2") {
    site.text = $("#id_name").text();
}
```

Comment: You HTML is invalid as you can't have duplicate IDs!

Comment: Do you really have multiple elements with the same id attribute on your page? Is site.text a variable name or is it an HTML element on your page?

Comment: @Teras first of all you are supposed to have unique ID values for your html tags, you can't have id_name for all the three divs they need to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($("#id_name:eq(1)").length > 0 && $("#id_name:eq(1)").text() === "text page2") {
    site.text = $("#id_name:eq(1)").text();
}
```

**Hint** use class instead of **ID**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use the same id for multiple elements. See [Why is it a bad thing to have multiple HTML elements with the same id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505350/why-is-it-a-bad-thing-to-have-multiple-html-elements-with-the-same-id-attribute)
2. Use classes instead
3. You can use [**:contains()**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```js
if ($(".class_name:contains(text page2)").length > 0) {
  $('body').text("text page2");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class_name">text page1</div>
<div class="class_name">text page2</div>
<div class="class_name">text page3</div>
```

Comment: @Teras, ok, even if they are different pages, the code should still working. Maybe I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: I can't change the html code. It is id. I want to use it in somewhere else and as default I have this information. So I though to check if this id exists and if its' innerText is equal to what I want. If both conditions true than I want to assign to the specific variable the inner text of id

Comment: Please is it possible to provide me a workaround like this one?

Comment: @Teras, if you must use the ids then change the code in my answer to use `if ($("[id="id_name"]:contains(text page2)")` instead

Comment: Why you use body instead of #id_name?

Comment: Why you don't assign the text to the variable I have like this ` site.text = $("#id_name").text();`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("[id*='id_name']").each(function(){
    if ($(this).html() == "text page2"){
    site.text($(this).html());  
}
});
```