# Javascript bool variable is out of scope

Tags: javascript

I try to declare bool variable and then check it, inside function, but I get error that there is unexpected identifier pointing to line where daysCreated is comparing to `false`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var daysCreated = false;

function createDays() {
 if daysCreated == false {
    //do something
    }
    daysCreated = true;
  }
}
```

function `createDays` is being called on button click inside document.

Comment: This is not valid syntax.  The condition in the `if` needs to be wrapped in brackets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript if statement syntax (need help)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758365/javascript-if-statement-syntax-need-help)

Comment: By the way *if(!daysCreated)*...

Comment: I would likely have passed the parameter to the function rather than working with a global `daysCreated` - and returned that "internal" value, keeps the code a bit more modular perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot your parenthesis.

```
function createDays() {
 if (daysCreated === false) {
    //do something
  }
  daysCreated = true;
}
```

Also, you have a stray closing curly brace, and it's probably better to check for strict equality (e.g. `===`).

Using a linter will catch things like this out of the gate. Here's [a tutorial on using ESLint](https://www.sitepoint.com/up-and-running-with-eslint-the-pluggable-javascript-linter/), for example.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with scope.

The `if` test must be between parenthesis: `if (condition)`

```
if (daysCreated === false) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid. You need brackets for your if statement like this:

```
function createDays() {
 if (daysCreated == false) {
    //do something
  }
  daysCreated = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
function createDays() {
   if (daysCreated === false) {
       //do something
   }
   daysCreated = true;
}
```

There was a stray {